# hashchange jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, hashchange

I have a form that adds a hash url to my domain on successful submit (http://domain.com/#addedhash)

I would like for the form to add a class to itself after the hash link is added.

I have this code, but it's not working for some reason:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("#addedhash") > -1 ) {
            $('.myclass').addClass('hide');
        } 
    });    
});
</script>
```

Maybe anyone can see a mistake here?

It works if the hash to the link is added by a button click, but if it's added by the form submission success result, the script doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: `if (window.location.href.indexOf("#addedhash") > -1) {...}` or better, check for `window.location.hash`

Comment: Why not add the class in the same place you're appending the url? Like in the form submission success by the sounds of it - adding a listener for this seems a bit overkill to me if I understand you correctly - this does nothing by the way `if (window.location.href.indexOf("#addedhash"))`

Comment: Your code is working properly in my end.

Comment: @RanaGhosh But `-1` is truthly value in javascript, i'm not sure how do you check it?!

Comment: Same code i have copied and add a manual div with class 'myclass'. And it's working on my end

Comment: I've added two buttons, one of them adds a hash and the code works, but it only works when hash is added by button click. While the hash is added during the form submit, script does not add any class. Any ideas?

Comment: you're checking for index of but not checking the value lol, check if its `> -1`

Comment: It added it after the first suggestions, no result

Comment: Does it add the hash to the URL, or does it reload the current page with the added hash? If it's the latter, then there is no `hashchange` event

Comment: Exactly, it does not reload the page, hash link is just added while staying on the page.

Comment: @KigoKigo - post your form handling code. Are you sure it's not getting refreshed, or is it just happening really fast and you think the only thing that's changing it the hash. i.e. are you specifically preventing the default action of the form submission and handling it yourself, adding the hash to the url in the process?

Comment: That's a wordpress payment plugin that captures credit card data and submits it, there is an option in the plugin settings to set a success URL. I set it to #download because it's mandatory for the page not to be refreshed, so the payment form remains in "processing" phase and just adds #download hash to the URL, so on that hash change, I am trying to add class to the form to hide it, because refreshing the page would ruin the whole point.

Comment: Again, just because you set the successURL to be `#download` doesn't mean the page doesn't get refreshed. Until you can prove that the page doesn't get refreshed, I'm going to assume that it is getting refreshed, which is where your problem lies. To see if I am correct, change `$(window).on('hashchange',function() {...` to `$(window).on('hashchange load',function() {...` and see if the DIV gets hidden. This will cause your code to get executed both on `hashchange` **and** when your page loads. I'm not saying this fixes your problem, but it determines what the real issue is.

Comment: Adam, I really appreciate your help. Anyways, the page wasn't reloading, strange but changing $(document).ready(function() { ... to jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... have fixed the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a submission of a form does not work the same way than a link does. It opens a new query. Hashes are controlled internally (DOM) by the link object, not the Form object.

Comment: So is there any other way I could add a class to an element when a hash link appears? I know I could do it by PHP after successful form submit, but know almost nothing at PHP. Thank you

Comment: I think you should add an even on submit, so you can handle those kind of situations. When the function called on submit returns false, the submitting is cancelled.

Comment: You have to specifically prevent the default action of submitting the form, and manipulate the hash yourself, in the submission handler. If you aren't doing that, then the page is getting reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Strange but changing `$(document).ready(function() { ...` to `jQuery(document).ready(function() { ...` have fixed the problem. Thank you.